# Angular 16: Can't get route input binding to work

Tags: angular, angular-router, angular-input

Angular 16 introduced a new way to easily parse route information and I wanted to utilize it since it avoids boilerplate code. However, I just can't get it to work and I'm not sure what I am doing wrong.

As described in their [documentation](https://angular.io/guide/router#getting-route-information) I added the new option to the router initialization:

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { bindToComponentInputs: true })],
  exports: [RouterModule],
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

Afterwards I added the `@Input()` binding to my `app.component.ts` file:

```
@Input() settings_id? = '';

  public ngOnInit(): void {
    if (this.settings_id !== '') {
      console.log(this.settings_id); <-- this doesn't fire since string remains "empty"
    }
  }
```

According to all the (limited) [resources](https://itnext.io/bind-route-info-to-component-inputs-new-router-feature-1d747e559dc4) I am able to find online this should already be sufficient. The URL I am calling is `http://localhost:4200?settings_id=2a39962d-c3c5-4ade-8a0f-1b7f97279a58`

Comment: You probably need a route with :settings_id rather than the app component. For example, admin/:settings_id

Comment: @ertucode I'm not trying to get a path param. Docs explicitly state that query params are also supported.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This component input binding only works on routes of the router :

```
  providers: [provideRouter([
    { component: ChildComponent, path: 'test'} // will work on ChildComponent
  ], withComponentInputBinding())],
```

But not on the root component.

Comment: Oh okay, I guess it makes sense that only routes directly handled by the Router have this functionality lol. 
Now it works as expected.